# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric with column insert

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error above when I try to insert this column into the database. What do I need to do fix this problem?

```
INSERT INTO School(GPA) 

GPA = CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(HS.XAPPLAPPMISC2), 8.2)) = 1 
          THEN LEFT(LTRIM(HS.XAPPLAPPMISC2), 8.2)
          ELSE NULL
      END,
FROM HighSchool HS
```

Comment: `LEFT(something,8.2)`?, why `8.2`?

Comment: Could you show us what type of fields in your table?

Comment: Is that really your exact code?   It's missing a "SELECT" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as I presume the column you're dealing with is int?

You could convert/cast the column to big int before doing your processing on it:

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(CONVERT(BIGINT,HS.XAPPLAPPMISC2)), 8.2)) = 1 THEN
                            LEFT(LTRIM(CONVERT(BIGINT,HS.XAPPLAPPMISC2)), 8.2)
```

You can see the microsoft documentation on this here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187745.aspx
The table shows the ranges of each type.

I hope this helps.

Another thing is that you're select left 8.2 which will ultimately give you left 8 unless I'm mistaken?